# How to show NCursesPanel on screen by c++ bindings of NCurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

DemoI am trying out the c++ bindings shipped with ncurses-5.9. It seems that it is not easy to show a panel with window inside on screen easily. Here is my code

```
class SpiderApplication : NCursesApplication
{
protected:
  int titlesize() const { return 2; };
  void title();

public:
  SpiderApplication() : NCursesApplication(TRUE) {}

  int run();
};

void SpiderApplication::title()
{
  const char * const titleText = "Demo";
  const int len = ::strlen(titleText);

  titleWindow->bkgd(screen_titles());
  titleWindow->addstr(0, (titleWindow->cols() - len) / 2, titleText);
  titleWindow->noutrefresh();
}

int SpiderApplication::run()
{
  NCursesPanel mystd;
  NCursesPanel P(mystd.lines() - titlesize(), mystd.cols(), titlesize() - 1, 0);
  P.label("Demo", NULL);
  P.show();
  ::getch();
  P.clear();

  return 0;
}
```

I suppose that the there should be a panel shown under titleline of this application. However, it doesn't. Do I miss something important here. Is there any example for how to use the c++ binding of ncurses?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on your problem? What happens when you run your program? What errors (if any) do you get? What do you expect to happen, and what really happens?

Comment: The panel doesn't show on screen. I have updated the description of the issue.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. running in a debugger, and setting a breakpoint at the `P.clear();` statement line, to see if it just skips your `getch()` call?

Comment: Also, do the title show?

Comment: Title shows well. and getch() also works because hitting any key on keyboard will dismiss the stdwin. I just cannot get the panel shown.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer for my own question.

To make panel shown on screen, `refresh()` call cannot be omitted. Here is the working code:

```
NCursesPanel mystd;
NCursesPanel P(mystd.lines() - titlesize(), mystd.cols(), titlesize() - 1, 0);
P.label("Demo", NULL);
P.show();
mystd.refresh();
::getch();
P.clear();
```